# Error arreglo de objetos en java

Tags: java, array

Tengo una duda acerca de esta error (estoy empezando con java):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous tree type: principal.Paciente     at
>   principal.Principal.main(Principal.java:20)
>   C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Aquí mi código: `Principal.java`:

```
package principal;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
         /*
         a[0].SetMatricula(12);
         a[0].SetNombre("Juan");
         a[0].getMatricula();
         */

        Paciente a[] = new Paciente[5];
        String nombre = "";
        int matricula = 0;
        char grupo = ' ';
        int grado = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre");
            nombre = leer.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingresa tu matricula");
            matricula = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingresa tu grupo");
            grupo = leer.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Ingresa tu grado");
            grado = leer.nextInt();
            leer.nextLine();
            a[i] = new Paciente(nombre, matricula, grupo, grado);
        }
    }
}
```

Clase `Paciente`:

```
public class Paciente {
    private String nombre;
    private int matricula;
    private char grupo;
    private int grado;


    public Paciente() {
        nombre = "";
        matricula = 0;
        grupo = ' ';
        grado = 0;
    }

    public Paciente(String n, int m, char g, int gg) {
        nombre = "";
        matricula = 0;
        grupo = ' ';
        grado = 0;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public char getGrupo() {
        return grupo;
    }

    public void setGrupo(char grupo) {
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }

    public int getGrado() {
        return grado;
    }

    public void setGrado(int grado) {
        this.grado = grado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que despues de capturar el grado haces un `leer.nextLine();` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si **realmente** necesitas dos contructores en tu clase `Paciente` los mismos deberían estar así:

```
   public Paciente()
   {
        this.nombre="";
        this.matricula=0;
        this.grupo=' ';
        this.grado=0;
    }

   public Paciente(String nombre,int matricula,char grupo,int grado)
   {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.matricula=matricula;
        this.grupo=grupo;
        this.grado=grado;
   }
```

Si no usas `this` los miembros no adquieren los valores que les pasas al hacer:

```
new Paciente(nombre,matricula,grupo,grado);
```

También, para mostrar los datos de tu clase `Paciente` sería bueno que la dotes de un método `toString`:

Por ejemplo:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
            "Nombre: "+this.nombre
            +" Matricula:"+this.matricula
            +" Grupo: "+this.grupo
            +" Grado: "+this.grado;
}
```

### Clase `Paciente` completa:

```
public class Paciente 
{
    private String nombre;
    private int matricula;
    private char grupo;
    private int grado;


    public Paciente()
   {
        this.nombre="";
        this.matricula=0;
        this.grupo=' ';
        this.grado=0;
    }

   public Paciente(String nombre,int matricula,char grupo,int grado)
   {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.matricula=matricula;
        this.grupo=grupo;
        this.grado=grado;
   }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public char getGrupo() {
        return grupo;
    }

    public void setGrupo(char grupo) {
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }

    public int getGrado() {
        return grado;
    }

    public void setGrado(int grado) {
        this.grado = grado;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
                "Nombre: "+this.nombre
                +" Matricula:"+this.matricula
                +" Grupo: "+this.grupo
                +" Grado: "+this.grado;
}

}
```

Si quieres ver los datos que hay en la clase, pon esto fuera del bucle `for` del Scanner:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

El error puede puede ser debido a tipos de dato. Es correcto lo que menciona **A. Cedano** en la declaración de los constructores, sin embargo yo declararía solamente uno por el momento, el siguiente

```
 public Paciente()
 {
    this.nombre="";
    this.matricula=0;
    this.grupo=' ';
    this.grado=0;
 }
```

En cuanto a la implementación al parecer estas declarando mal el arreglo, deberia ser:

```
  Paciente[] a = new Paciente[5];
```

Prueba con este ejemplo. Ya no es necesario declarar nuevamente las variables en el Main, realiza una instancia de la clase Paciente, llena los campos directamente cuando los ingresa el usuario y asignalos a tu arreglo de Pacientes.

```
    public class Principal
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 

        {
            Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
            Paciente[] a = new Paciente[5];


            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                Paciente p = new Paciente();
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre");
                p.nombre=leer.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu matricula");
                p.matricula=leer.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu grupo");
                p.grupo=leer.next().charAt(0);
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu grado");
                p.grado=leer.nextInt();
                leer.nextLine();
                a[i]= p;
            }

         //Si quieres mostrar los elementos que tiene tu arreglo
         Console.WriteLine(a[0].nombre + " " + a[0].matricula + " " + a[0].grupo + " " + a[0].grado);
        }
    }
```

Se puede hacer de una manera mas limpia utilizando listas en lugar de arreglos. Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.